# c# webserver working on local (127.0.0.1) but no on public

Tags: c#, web, ip, server

[I used this web server for c#](https://gist.github.com/aksakalli/9191056):
I tried other projects too, but I can't connect to my IP.

This is the main function:

```
/// <param name="path">Directory path to serve.</param>
public SimpleHTTPServer(string path)
{
    //get an empty port
    TcpListener l = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
    l.Start();
    int port = ((IPEndPoint)l.LocalEndpoint).Port;
    l.Stop();
    this.Initialize(path, port);
}
```

For example:

```
127.0.0.1 - working
localhost - working
122.211.2.27 - not working
```

Comment: What does it do instead? errors? incorrect values?

Comment: did you try to change `IPAddress.Loopback` to anything else valid for your machine?

Comment: Ofc! If I use another IP on machine it just don't work, else it works only on local.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is likely related to the fact that you explicitly create the `TcpListener` bound to the loopback:

```
TcpListener l = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
```

read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4zw1w3a(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details about how to create a listener without an explicit binding or bound to a different ip address.

Comment: IPEndPoint ipLocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000); 
I tryed this, but not working.